# Gather div class into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

My current html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display:block;" id="item0"><!--- Stuff --></div>
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;" id="item1"><!--- Stuff --></div>
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;" id="item2"><!--- Stuff --></div>
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;" id="item3"><!--- Stuff --></div>
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none;" id="item4"><!--- Stuff --></div>
```

And then I have a back/forward link which call the corresponding javascript function, it looks like this:

```
 function switchNextItem() {  
    var element0 = document.getElementById('item0');
    var element1 = document.getElementById('item1');
    var element2 = document.getElementById('item2');
    var element3 = document.getElementById('item3');
    var element4 = document.getElementById('item4');

    if (element0.style.display == 'block')  {
        element0.style.display = 'none';  
        element1.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (element1.style.display == 'block') {
        element1.style.display = 'none';
        element2.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (element2.style.display == 'block') {
        element2.style.display = 'none';
        element3.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (element3.style.display == 'block') {
        element3.style.display = 'none';
        element4.style.display = 'block';
    } else if (element4.style.display == 'block') {
        element4.style.display = 'none';
        element0.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Are there any possibilities for me to make this more dynamically?

Thanks! (I'm not familiar with javascript).

Comment: Would you be interested in diving into the simple world of `jQuery`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd love [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): http://jsfiddle.net/TCQum/.

```
function switchNextItem() {
    $('div.wrapper:visible')  .hide()    .next()      .show();
//     select visible div   | hide it | goto next | show that one
}
```

Edit: A more precise one:

```
function switchNextItem() {
    var next = $('div.wrapper:visible:eq(0)')
               .hide()
               .next('div.wrapper'); // next one will be stored in next

    if(next.length === 0) { // if there is no next one, show first one agan
        $('div.wrapper:eq(0)').show();
    } else { // otherwise show next one
        next.show();
    }
}
```

And with `.prev`:

```
function switchNextItem() {
    var prev = $('div.wrapper:visible:eq(0)')
               .hide()
               .prev('div.wrapper'); // prev one will be stored in prev

    if(prev.length === 0) { // if there is no prev one, show last one
        $('div.wrapper:last').show();
    } else { // otherwise show prev one
        prev.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gah! I've been on the `Java`, `C#` and `C++` sides too much! Thank you, I'll check this out.

Comment: This is not equivalent if more than one is block (may not be possible).  You also have to handle the wrap around of the last case there, `next` won't wrap to the first item.

Comment: You two are the best. Both solutions are working. However, pimvdb, I'm wondering if there is any `$('div.wrapper:visible')  .hide().previous().show();` way to go where I have a back button?

Comment: @Julian Assange: It's called `.prev` :)

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks, if I could accept both of your answers and triple vote them up it would be great, otherwise, I'm just really grateful - a new world has opened! :)

Comment: @pimvdb: Just one last question: how can I write same sort of reset with when going backwards? That stuff with if-else?

Comment: @Julian Assange: Quite the same, but instead of `:eq(0)`, use `:last`. (And, instead of `:eq(0)` you could also use `:first` if that clears things up.)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work.

```
function switchNextItem() {  
    var items=['item0','item1','item2','item3','item4'];

    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        var element = document.getElementById(items[i]);

        if (element.style.display == 'block')  {
            element.style.display = 'none';  

            var nextElement = document.getElementById(items[(i+1) % items.length]);
            nextElement.style.display = 'block';

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually moving to the first at the end again, I forgot about that. However, you'd need `(i+1) % items.length` though.

Comment: Thanks both of you for two good answers. I will try this out. :)

Comment: Good point, updated.  As I was typing it I though of that but forgot to check if the parentheses were needed.